# How to optimize tagged words in the Tkinter Text Widget in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tags

I am using the TKinter Text widget in python 3.6 to tag each word with some metadata.  I find that once I have over 800 words, the program starts to run very slowly and at 3200 it is almost non responsive.  I was wondering if there way to optimize my code so it can handle many more tagged words?  Or provide the widget access to more memory if that would help.

Here is a very simplified version of my program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

def createWidgets(root):
    textcanvas = ScrolledText(root, insertofftime=0) 
    textcanvas.pack()
    populate(textcanvas)
    return textcanvas

def populate(textcanvas):
    for i in range(5000):
        textcanvas.insert(tk.END, "word ", "TAG:>{:d}".format(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root =tk.Tk()
    createWidgets(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the text widget should be able to handle thousands of tags without much of a performance hit. However, there are certain characteristics of your data that can impact this.

Based on your example, your data has one of the characteristics that will result in poor performance: you are inserting 25,000 characters with 5,000 tags, all without a newline.

This is what the [canonical text widget documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M165) says about performance considerations (emphasis added to highlight the problem you're likely seeing):

> Text widgets should run efficiently under a variety of conditions. The text widget uses about 2-3 bytes of main memory for each byte of text, so texts containing a megabyte or more should be practical on most workstations. Text is represented internally with a modified B-tree structure that makes operations relatively efficient even with large texts. Tags are included in the B-tree structure in a way that allows tags to span large ranges or have many disjoint smaller ranges without loss of efficiency. Marks are also implemented in a way that allows large numbers of marks. In most cases it is fine to have large numbers of unique tags, or a tag that has many distinct ranges.
>
> One performance problem can arise if you have hundreds or thousands of different tags that all have the following characteristics: the first and last ranges of each tag are near the beginning and end of the text, respectively, or a single tag range covers most of the text widget. The cost of adding and deleting tags like this is proportional to the number of other tags with the same properties. In contrast, there is no problem with having thousands of distinct tags if their overall ranges are localized and spread uniformly throughout the text.
>
> *Very long text lines can be expensive, especially if they have many marks and tags within them.*
>
> The display line with the insert cursor is redrawn each time the cursor blinks, which causes a steady stream of graphics traffic. Set the insertOffTime attribute to 0 avoid this.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I'm adding an example to my question, because I've tried to create a simplified version of my code, and it is still moving extremely slow.  Just trying to select text or move the cursor in this Text widget is taking a few seconds.  Any suggestions or is it that the Text widget really shouldn't be handling this many tags?  Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the tags, it's the fact you've inserted 25,000 characters without a single newline. Note in the above quote where it says _"Very long text lines can be expensive, especially if they have many marks and tags within them."_ - that's exactly your situation.